# Bootstrap column class not following margins or container fluid class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using cards to display information on a website. I want the cards to be side by side with each other.
I heard that the way to do this is to put each card into a column.

When I do this, all the spacing that I wanted for my 2 cards is gone. The 1st card has no spacing between the left side of the screen and the 2nd card is right against the 1st card.
Other elements inside my container-fluid div usually have a bit of margin but the column doesn't.

Code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="card mb-3" style="width: 22rem;">
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item">Name: User</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Email: User@email.com</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password: </label>
                <input id="exampleInputPassword1" type="password" disabled value="{{session['password']}}" style="width: 10rem">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20"  fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-eye-fill"
                     viewBox="0 0 16 16" style="margin-top:-5px; margin-left: 5px" id="iconUnselected"
                     onmousedown="document.getElementById('iconUnselected').classList.add('d-none');
                              document.getElementById('iconSelected').classList.remove('d-none')
                              document.getElementById('exampleInputPassword1').setAttribute('type', 'text')">
                    <path d="M10.5 8a2.5 2.5 0 1 1-5 0 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 5 0z"/>
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 8s3-5.5 8-5.5S16 8 16 8s-3 5.5-8 5.5S0 8 0 8zm8 3.5a3.5 3.5 0 1 0 0-7 3.5 3.5 0 0 0 0 7z"/>
                </svg>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-eye d-none"
                     viewBox="0 0 16 16" id="iconSelected" style="margin-top:-5px; margin-left: 5px"
                     onmouseup="document.getElementById('iconSelected').classList.add('d-none');
                              document.getElementById('iconUnselected').classList.remove('d-none')
                              document.getElementById('exampleInputPassword1').setAttribute('type', 'password')">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M16 8s-3-5.5-8-5.5S0 8 0 8s3 5.5 8 5.5S16 8 16 8zM1.173 8a13.134 13.134 0 0 0 1.66 2.043C4.12 11.332 5.88 12.5 8 12.5c2.12 0 3.879-1.168 5.168-2.457A13.134 13.134 0 0 0 14.828 8a13.133 13.133 0 0 0-1.66-2.043C11.879 4.668 10.119 3.5 8 3.5c-2.12 0-3.879 1.168-5.168 2.457A13.133 13.133 0 0 0 1.172 8z"/>
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 5.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zM4.5 8a3.5 3.5 0 1 1 7 0 3.5 3.5 0 0 1-7 0z"/>
                </svg>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Status: Standard</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editInfo">Edit Info</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteAccount">Delete Account</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-3 col-100" style="width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">About</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Sample About Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this or better yet find a more effective way of getting the 2 cards next to each other? Thanks

[image]

See in this image, the margin is not the same (shown by red arrow). Below, I had a card that obeys the proper margins given by container-fluid but the above cards in the div do not and have no margins. I need this to be exact. Don't add margin to the cards because there are still some discrepancies when zoomed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is quite simple. I'll use some older code you wrote since it is easier to work with. Use a row div around all your cards like before:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class='row'>
         <div class="card mb-3" style="width: 22rem;">
             <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">1st card</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
              </div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card mb-3 col-100" style="width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">2nd card</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="card mb-3 col-100" style="width: 18rem;">  
    <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">2nd card</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

The difference is that you have to wrap it each card in a column. So do this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class='row'>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="card mb-3" style="width: 22rem;">
             <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">1st card</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
              </div>
           </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="card mb-3 col-100" style="width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">2nd card</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        </div>
<div class="card mb-3 col-100" style="width: 18rem;">  
    <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">2nd card</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

If it doesn't work just yet, you should just change around the number on col-sm-4 so change the 4 to a 5 or something else if it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Add `row` class after `container-fluid`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card mb-3" style="width: 22rem;">
           <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">1st card</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
         </div>
       <div class="card mb-3 col-100" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">2nd card</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/49u10jLo/1/

Comment: Oh sorry -- forgot to copy that in.

Comment: Also the code still gives the same result, the cards are packed together. I'll edit a snip of it.

Answer (score 1):

I have added `flexbox` class in this to add dynamic spacing between cards as you wanted. There are three types of spacing you can include as per your requirement which are:-

- Space-around(`justify-content-around`): This will leave equal spacing around cards.
- Space-between(`justify-content-between`): This will leave all space in between cards.
- Space-evenly(`justify-content-evenly`): This will leave equal spaces in between all cards. **my recommendation**

Note: For left and right spacing you can add margin by adding class (`mx-2`), this is optional.

Code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-evenly">
    <div class="card">
           <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">1st card</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
         </div>
       <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">2nd card</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That wasn't really what I had intended for as every thing is just centered now. I'll put a picture of what I really need.

Comment: @JamesHuang, I am still awaiting for image to get an idea of what actually you want. Image in your comment is still not providing enough info.

Comment: In the image, there is a red arrow showing that the space between the div that is in a row and another div that isn't in the row is different. This is because the div in the row doesn't follow container-fluid margins. In your code, the row divs are centered which isn't what I want. I wanted the divs to be aligned with the same margin to the left of the screen.

Comment: @JamesHuang, Please have a look i have removed the row to remove any margin that were applied by that class. Now it will have margin that are applied on parent divs

Comment: It looks like it works, but if I shorten some of the text it goes back to being centered. I think I will have to include more of my own code since other things are affecting this.

Comment: Good to hear it is working initially. If you want help on making the text responsive and resolve that centered issue please provide more info about the issue if you need help on that

Comment: I have added more code that shows  better the style of the page I was making.

Answer (score 0):

My code is bellow. It worked.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class='row'>
        <div class="card mb-3 mx-3" style="width: 22rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">1st card</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">2nd card</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to make margin to 1st card. It worked. I am sorry for my poor English.

Comment: It looks good as a a start but if you zoom in a bunch, the margin will be off. I'll include some more code with a reference card.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
        <title>
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class='row'>
                <div class="card mb-3 ml-3 mr-1" style="width: 22rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">1st card</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card mb-3 ml-3" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">2nd card</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I made 2nd card have margin too. I am sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Maybe you should include images to how your code has been showing for you so I don't have to change tags to see it for myself all the time. You could also put the code as a snippet like some of the other answers.

Comment: First code was like this. <div class="card mb-3  mx-3"> for 1st card. Second answer is like this.  <div class="card mb-3 ml-3 mr-1"> for 1st card, and <div class="card mb-3 ml-3"> for 2nd card. I am sorry for my poor English.

Comment: I saw that but it doesn't really change anything on my machine. Try running the code yourself and sharing a snippet or make the code a code snippet.

Comment: I sent you whole html code. It works correctly on my device.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't since bootstrap isn't even loaded correctly. None of the cards even show up when I run this code. It is just default font.